# Add markers to markerarray in c++

Tags: ros, markers, markerarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to add markers to a markerarray but i am unable to find the line of code that has to be used for this. Ot is probably pretty simple but I am inexperienced with c++ and ros.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35246/add-markers-to-markerarray-in-c++/) by [Fredje](https://answers.ros.org/users/2494/fredje/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`MarkerArray ma; ma.markers.push_back(mark)`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gnykumar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28335/gnykumar@gmail.com/) on 2020-04-22**:
what is the difference in insert and push_back

MarkerArray ma;

MarkerArray mark;

ma.markers.insert(ma.makers.end(), mark.makers.begin(), mark.markers.end());

vs

ma.markers.push_back(mark);

**Comment by [Hazel-rah](https://answers.ros.org/users/144712/hazel-rah/) on 2023-06-08**:
I usually work in python, but it might be that push_back can be in loop easier than your insert line, or that push_back is faster. Could also be neither

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much, that works.

---

Originally posted by [Fredje](https://answers.ros.org/users/2494/fredje/) with karma: 51 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2020-09-06**:
This is not where you comment actually.